# How to write a file in jsp path instead of directory path?

Tags: java, jsp

We have a web application hosted on WebSphere that upload images to a directory. The directory path is determined by a parameter value that is stored on database, let's say the parameter name is "dir" `[dir = ../images/]`

Where "images" folder is under the same application on WebSphere, so the system uploads the image on the folder under WebSphere

On another page, the system retrieves the image and shows it to the user, we wanted the system to read images from database instead of reading it from physical directory. When the system tries to access the image `[id: img123.jpg]`, the system automatically sets the image path to be `[dir + imgid -> ../images/img123.jpg]`

So we changed the dir parameter value to be `[dir = ../images/img.jsp?]`
 which automatically made the system to open the image from path `[../images/img.jsp?img123.jpg]` and it worked correctly in reading the image on the webpage as the jsp responds with image bytes stored on database

But now we are not able to write the file as the system tries to write the file to the path `[../images/img.jsp?]` which will not work.

Do you have any solution to this, or any other suggestions on how to achieve this without making changes to the system itself?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this - take the parameter and cutoff what you don't need:

`String dirToUpload = dir.substring(0,dir.indexOf("img.jsp?"));`

Comment: I can't do changes to the main web application, so I can't change the value of the parameter programatically

Comment: @jmdanial you can't change the upload-image section and the display-image section? What can you change?

Comment: Only the value of the dir parameter on database, and I can add jsp files or depoly any other application that can achieve what we want. But without changing on the main web application

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved as the main web application has stored the image under the physical path "/images/img.jsp?", as it created a directory with the name "img.jsp?"
Now, I will develop a listener which stores the physical images to database